# What does it mean to write $|||x|||$ rather than $||x||$?

Tags: notation, normed-spaces

I am familiar with the notation $||x||$ meaning some norm of $x$. I have just come across the notation $|||x|||$ (in a text that also uses the former for norms). What is the difference?

Comment: Sometimes if authors are using two different norms in a proof, they will use triple bar notation to denote a separate norm. It's far from being the best notation..

Comment: Usually, the difference is that one uses the two symbols when considering different norms in the same context, to distinguish the two norms.

Comment: I have found it in http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0759v3. They seem to use the $|||f|||$ for functions $f$ and $||x||$ for vectors $x$. See their definition of their function space above (3) on page 5.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the triple bar notation is used for the subordinate norm for the linear transformation i.e. if $f: (E,||.||_E)\to (F,||.||_F)$ is a linear transformation then we definite the subordinate norm of $f$ by

$$|||f|||=\sup_{x\in E\setminus\{0_E\}}\frac{||f(x)||_F}{||x||_E}$$

Comment: Could this perhaps mean, in the above-mentioned paper, that $|||f|||_{\omega, p} = ||f(x)||_{\omega, p}$?

Comment: Don't most people "usually" use $||f||$ for the operator norm? That is all I have ever seen.